# How do I make a spreadsheet sum up transactions only if its by the same customer?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

So my team is trying to calculate a bonus for our employees based on their collections. Basically I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can sum up the total amount collected per customer in a month, and then we subtract $50 per customer from the total and the remainder is bonused.

My coworkers aren't very tech savvy so ideally we would just pull the report that tells us every collection (It comes out as a .csv) we copy the data and paste it into another spreadsheet, and then it does the math for us.

The complicated part being how do I get the spreadsheet to know if two transactions are from the same member.

I have a spreadsheet created that uses "=if" to find out if the transaction above the current sell is the same member, and then if it is it will add it together. Issue is this doesn't work past a set amount of transactions, suppose a member has 6 transactions in one month, I would need to have 6 "=if" functions inside each other. Then any outlier wouldn't be counted.

Please let me know if you would like more information or have an idea on how I could make this work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a spreadsheet with a list of transactions, you can use the `SUMIF` formula to sum up the transactions only if they are by the same customer. Here's an example

1. Create a table with the following columns: Transaction ID, Customer Name, and Transaction Amount
2. Enter the transaction details in the table
3. In a new cell, enter the `SUMIF` formula: `=SUMIF(B2:B10,"Customer Name",C2:C10)`. This formula will sum up all the transactions with the customer name "Customer Name" in column B and the corresponding transaction amounts in column C
4. Replace "Customer Name" in the formula with the actual customer name you want to sum up

You can repeat this process for each customer you want to sum up. The `SUMIF` formula will only sum up the transactions that match the specified customer name.

Comment: So I did try this, but the issue is that the customer name is constantly changing. We have about 100,000 customers and new ones every day. Is there some other way to have it sum?

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can sum up the total amount
> collected per customer in a month, and then we subtract $50 per
> customer from the total and the remainder is bonused.

Please try the following

```
=QUERY({A1:C,INDEX(TEXT(A1:A,"mmmm"))},
              "select Col2, sum(Col3)-50 where Col1 is not null 
               group by Col2 PIVOT Col4 label sum(Col3)-50 '' ",1)
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]